# Mockito тестировние void метода

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Тестируемый метод

```
public boolean delete(Long id) {
    Message message = messageRepository.findOne(id);
    if (message == null) {
        throw  new DataNotFoundException("Data with id=" + id + " not found.");
    }
    messageRepository.delete(id);
    return true;
}
```

Тест:

```
@Test
public void delete() throws Exception {
    //prepare
    MessageServiceImp spy = spy(new MessageServiceImp(messageRepository));
    messageServiceImp.save(MESSAGE); //создаю объект, пробовал и не создавать результат одинаков
    doReturn(true).when(spy).delete(ID);
    //testing
    boolean testMessage = messageServiceImp.delete(ID);
    //validate
    verify(messageRepository).delete(ID);
}
```

Тест не проходит получаю:

> .exception.DataNotFoundException: Data with id=1 not found.

Что делаю не так?

---

Добавление MessageRepository

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long>{
}
```

Comment: а что вы пытаетесь протестировать? опишите словами ваш тест.

Comment: Я хочу проверить, что метод delete получив id выполнит удаление и вернет true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой вариант.

Тестируемый метод

```
public void delete(Long id) {
    // так делать плохо
    // добавлено по просьбе вопрошающего
    try {
        // проверку на существование и пр. должен делать MessageRepository
        messageRepository.delete(id);
    } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
        throw new DataNotFoundException("Data with id=" + id + " not found.");
    }
}
```

Тест

```
private static final Long ID = 123;

// интерфейс, а не реализация
private MessageRepository messageRepository;

@Test
public void detele_delegateToRepository() throws Exception {
    // подготовка
    messageRepository = mock(MessageRepository.class);
    // не знаю как у вас класс называется - будем считать Subject
    Subject subject = new Subject(messageRepository);

    // действие
    subject.delete(ID);

    // проверка
    verify(messageRepository).delete(ID);
}

@Test(expected = DataNotFoundException.class)
public void detele_throwsException() throws Exception {
    // подготовка
    messageRepository = mock(MessageRepository.class);
    // не знаю как у вас класс называется - будем считать Subject
    Subject subject = new Subject(messageRepository);

    when(messageRepository.delete(ID)).thenThrow(new EmptyResultDataAccessException());

    // действие
    subject.delete(ID);
}
```

Это все что вам надо тестировать. Остальные тесты должны быть у класса который реализует MessageRepository.

Comment: boolean и return messageRepository.delete(id);  == Incompatible types.

Comment: покажите ваш MessageRepository

Comment: Добавил выше в тело вопроса.

Comment: @SergeiR исправил код

Comment: Ну а проверка если ли такой id? У меня она сдесь же до вызова messageRepository.delete(id);

Comment: а зачем нужна эта проверка? такая проверка уже делается в JpaRepository.

Comment: Ну а если я хочу возвращать кастомный exception? Собственно у меня так и есть/было.

Comment: на стандартные исключения в Spring есть обработчики. на ваше не будет. но не проблема - я добавлю обертку.

Comment: добавил исключение и тест на него

Comment: А предположим я убираю проверку в сервисе и делаю без кастомного исключения, актуальных причин для него на самом деле нет. Но все равно метод удаления надо протестировать на исключение если такой id не наден. Это надо делать в тестах контроллера?

Comment: если контроллер реагирует на исключение - тестируйте в контроллере. вы тестируете поведение. если у сущности нет поведения, то не надо ничего тестировать.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вашу мысль, точнее вроде и понимаю, а вроде и нет ) Контроллер имеет метод который вызывает другой метод и так по цепочке. В итоге исключение выкидывает MessageRepository, а точнее JpaRepository. Контроллер же возвращает, отправляет сообщение о исключении клиенту. Постман мне показывает  org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException ну и соответствующий message. Когда я делаю тест контроллера на это исключение получаю или Expected exception или если в стиле BDD то и вообще ошибки от mockito.

Comment: создайте лучше новый вопрос. контроллер в оригинальном вопросе отсутствует.